# Python Regex: (\w+) not picking up up numbers with 2 digits or less

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to use python's regex to recognize 3 tokens from the user which can all be composed of either letters or numbers.

Here is the code I was using:

```
    match = re.search(r'(\w+)(\w+)(\w+)', inputStr)
    if not match:
        print("Not valid")
    else:
        numWord1 = match.group(0)
        numword2 = match.group(1)
        numWord3 = match.group(2)

    print(num1)
```

where inputStr comes from raw_input(). I ran my code, and here's what I get for each input

```
      I typed: 1 2 3
      I got: Not valid

      I typed: 11 22 33
      I got: Not valid

      I typed: 111 222 333
      I got: 111

      I typed: 1 hello 3
      I got: hello

      I typed: hello 2 3
      I got: hello
```

I thought \w matched any letter, digit, or underscore, and by including the + I would get 1 or more instances of it in my group.

Comment: You have spaces in your strings but it's not in your regex. Your regex, right now, will only match words that consist of 3 or more characters.

Comment: Try `(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)`

Comment: You're all right, thanks! I forgot that the whitespace needed to be matched (guess I was thinking about the scanner in C). Also, match.group(0) returns the whole string I typed in, whereas math.group(1) returns the first grouping. Are the match groupings not zero indexed?

Comment: Anna, no, [groups are one-indexed](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match.group).  This is consistent with the notation for backreferences (`\1`, `\2`, ...) in the replacement text of a regex substitution.  See also [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) - `\g<0>` refers to the whole matched string, just like `match.group(0)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\w` does not match the spaces between the numbers — as you correctly pointed out, `\w` matches a letter, digit, or underscore, *but not a space*.  Try:

```
match = re.search(r'(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)', inputStr)
```

`\s+` matches one or more whitespace characters between the groups of digits.

**Example** as tested in Python 3:

```
>>> print(re.search(r'(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)',input('? ')).group(1))
? 1 2 3
1
```

Answer (score 2):

> thought \w matched any letter, digit, or underscore

Yes but `\w` does not match spaces eg.

`1 2 3`

`r'(\w+)(\w+)(\w+)'`

Your pattern is looking for any letter digit or underscore, 3 times or more